# Negative prompt lists: will they contribute to search engines indexing?

Tags: discussion

I randomly stumbled upon the question [How do users create these dense-keyword prompts for leonardo.ai?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/133/how-do-users-create-these-dense-keyword-prompts-for-leonardo-ai).

In the post the user included a prompt example. As I skipped thru the text I realized that (to be fair as expected) the Negative Prompt included many NSFW words. It is worth noticing that considering that some models are indeed biased towards potentially unsafe results, it is perfectly reasonable to have such a prompt in the first place,  so as the site grows I only expect people to include more "bad word" in their posts, especially when you consider some proposals about always including generations details for image examples.

Therefore I was wondering what the impact on the site will be in relation to search engine indexing.

I would also point out that a long list of NSFW works in a post would be the something Smoke Detector would probably flag... but since the team running it is currently on strike let's for now forget about it existance.

Comment: (Wait, really...?  I don't know what "futa" means, but the rest seem like normal words to me.  I checked this before posting.)

Comment: Your is "tame" compared to average. Often, people go quite overboard. [This one](https://www.reddit.com/r/StableDiffusion/comments/xwu5od/about_that_huge_long_negative_prompt_list/) tries to prevent " anatomy hallucinations by including words that could be taken out of context. I also saw people adding nsfw words in the negative when using biased model that otherwise often produce unsafe pictures even without any trigger prompt.

Comment: note on the charcoal strike: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391871/997587